# Python - list index out of range - genetic algorithm

Tags: python, list, genetic-algorithm, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm having problems with my code and I know this problem is simple but I just can't figure it out how to solve it, I'll really appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
            import random
            from math import *
            def create_population(dim,pn):
                t = log(factorial(dim**2),2)
                b = int(t+1)
                d = ""
                indarray = []
                bits_array=[]
                #print("bits usados: ",b)
                for x in range(pn):
                    for y in range(b) :
                        if random.randint(0,400000) %2:
                            d = "1"+d
                        else:
                            d="0"+d

                        num=int(d,2)%factorial(dim**2)
                    bits_array.append(d)
                    indarray.append(num)

                    #print("\n index #",len(indarray),": ",num)
                    d=""
                return indarray,dim,bits_array,b

            def i2ms(index,b):
                squares=[]
                a=init_a(b)
                i=0
                t=b
                b = (b**2)-1
                for i in range(len(index)):
                    s=""
                    cont = 1
                    while(index[i]>0):
                        c = factorial(b)
                        ind =(index[i]/c)
                        s = s+str(a[int(ind)])+" "
                        del a[(int(ind))]
                        index[i] = index[i]%c
                        b-=1
                        cont +=1
                    for i in range(len(a)):
                        s = s+str(a[i])+" "
                    squares.append(s)
                    a = init_a(t)
                    b = t
                    b = (b**2)-1
                    s=""
                return squares
            def init_a(b):
                a=[]
                for i in range(b**2):
                    a.append(i+1)
                return a
            def score(squares):
                scores=[]
                print("\n")
                for i in range(len(squares)):
                    r = squares[i]
                    r = r.split(' ')
                    n = int(sqrt(len(r)))
                    nd = r
                    goal = n * (n * n + 1) / 2;
                    nd.reverse()
                    m = [[nd.pop() for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
                    #print ("Cubo #",i+1,": \n")
                    #for i in range(n):
                        #print(m[i],'\n')
                    min_sum,max_sum= 0,0
                    minn = 1
                    maxx = n * n
                    for i in range (n):
                        min_sum += minn
                        minn += 1
                        max_sum += maxx
                        maxx += 1
                    min_b,max_b = abs(goal - min_sum), abs(goal - max_sum)
                    if min_sum < max_sum:
                         final_b = max_sum
                    else:
                        final_b = min_sum
                    total_cases = 2 * n + 2
                    bias = total_cases * final_b
                    fitness = bias
                    #print ("Max score: ",fitness)
                    for i in range(n):
                        s =0
                        for j in range(n):
                            s +=int(m[i][j])
                        fitness -= abs(goal-s)
                    for j in range(n):
                        s=0
                        for i in range(n):
                            s += int(m[i][j])
                        fitness -= abs(goal-s)
                    s = 0

                    if n%2 == 1:
                        for i in range(n):
                            s+= int(m[i][i])
                        fitness -= abs(goal-s)
                        m.reverse()
                        s = 0
                        for i in range(n):
                            s+= int(m[i][i])
                        fitness -= abs(goal-s)

                    #print("Actual score: ",fitness,"\n")
                    scores.append(int(fitness))
                #print("goal",goal)
                return scores,bias

            def breed(popul,score,breed_size,b):#popul= la poblacion , score : sus notas ind, breed_size, tamaño de poblacion que esco
            #escogeremos, b numero de bites;
            #Calculamos las medidas de la poblacion a "mergear"
                print(popul)
                print(score)
                maxx = max(score)
                #Acomodamos los cubos(en binario) con su respectivo score
                breed_pop=[]
                new_pop=[]
                for y in range(breed_size):
                    for z in score:
                        if score[z] == maxx:
                            breed_pop.append(popul[z])
                            del score[z]
                            del popul[z]
                        maxx= max(score)
                        print(breed_pop)


                if breed_pop>breed_size:
                    breed_pop.pop()
                    print(breed_pop)
                ##sorted(pop_dict.values())
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                #Dar Dimensiones y determinar la poblacion inicial
                print("dimensiones?")
                n = input()
                print("poblacion?")
                pn = input()
                print("breed size?")
                p= int(input())
                ##g = input()
                #Pasar los datos de dim y pob por el metodo de create_population, devuelve una lista con los index del cubo y su dimensiones
                ind,b,bits_a,bitsn= create_population(int(n),int(pn))
                #Convertimos cada uno de esos indices a un cubo magico con i2ms, devuelve un array de cubos magicos
                squares = i2ms(ind,b)
                '''print("\n")
                for i in range(len(squares)):
                    print("Cubo #",i+1,": " , squares[i])
                    #Pasamos cada cubo por score, nos dara el puntaje de cada cubo, devuelve una lista con los scores y el puntaje maximo
                '''
                scores,perfect = score(squares)
                breed(bits_a,scores,p,bitsn)
                '''for y in range(len(scores)):
                    print(scores[y],"/",perfect)
            '''
```

I'm using dimension = 3, population =10, and breed_size=4 but I keep getting:

if score[z] ==max 
IndexError: list index out of range

Edit:
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "squaresolver.py",line 156 in 
breed(bits:a,scores,p,bitsn)
File "squaresolver.py", line 125, in breed
if score[z] == maxx:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: show the complete traceback, and identify the line it points to in your code

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** reproducible example instead of dumping your entire code here and include the **full stack trace** which has helpful information such as exactly what line the error occurs on and how it was called.

Comment: In general, this is probably caused by the numerous places in your code you use the error-prone method of trying to iterate over a list by indexes, instead of values directly. **Don't**: `for i in range(len(x)): x[i]`. **Do**: `for thing in x: thing`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i know im posting it the wrong way ( I imagined it) this is my first time posting a question, ill edit it asap

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "score[z]" when you do "for z in score", z is not an index, is a value of the score list.

You can just do

```
if z == maxx
```

Answer (score 0):

As you delete things in a list, you end up with index problems using `range(len)`. If you have a list and then delete an item in it, you end up with a list whose length is now one less. This leads to `IndexErrors` as you try to access up to the original `len(list)`.

Perhaps think of copying the original and working with that.

Comment: thanks!! It worked, sorry for being so newbie! and thanks again